# Facebook like button on mobile website - check session from the Facebook App, not browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Lets say I have simple Facebook Like button on my website, like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.mywebsite.com/" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

If I access my page from a mobile device and click on the like button, it will ask me to log into the Facebook account in the browser even though I an logged in the Facebook App.

Question: Is there any way to make a Like button to check the Facebook session from the application, not the browser, on the mobile devices? So when I click on the Like button from a mobile device (that has the FB APP installed) it will "accept" my like without the login process into browser?

Thanks!

Comment: No, that is not possible. There is no connection between the Facebook App and the browser that could help with this.

Comment: You can't get the login session from the native Facebook app in your browser. Anyways, if it is of any help, in iOS the new login flow uses `SafariViewController` so most users should be logged in with Safari at least: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9